# tocloft.sty \|@chapter undefined

Tags: errors, tocloft

I have been working on my CV which I was editing on a different computer where it was compiling normally.  However, when installing MiKTeX and Texmaker on a new computer to make some edits, I get the error:

> `\@chapter undefined from the tocloft.sty package on line 268, even though I do not have any line 268.`

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}
\newlength{\outerbordwidth}
\pagestyle{empty}
\raggedbottom
\raggedright
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\robustify\cftdotfill

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please post the minimal code example on this site as links are not visited by all of us.

Comment: The bug is fixed in the version currently on CTAN `2.3i`. It will reach your installation soon, or you can grab  `tocloft.sty` from there and put it in your work repertory.

Comment: @jfbu How can I go about changing it to the CTAN version?

Comment: a priori download `tocloft.dtx` and `tocloft.ins` from https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tocloft and run `tex tocloft.ins` in the repertory of your current project (where you will have put both these files; I just tested it works. Keep only `tocloft.sty` after that and leave it there in the repertory of your latex project.)

Comment: The new `\@cftifundefined` macro seems buggy

Answer (score 1):

You can download the ready-to-install tocloft.tds.zip from [here](https://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) on CTAN and unzip it in `C\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\`, then refresh the FNDB via `MiKTeX Options`.

Note however it should be updated officially in the distribution within the next couple of days.